# Checking user != null although the user is authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a question about asp.net mvc 5.
In some actions although the user is authorized, after getting user via his ID, it is checked that the user != null. Why do they check for user != null?

```
[Authorize, /* with some other attributes */]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    // ...
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    // why they check user != null?
    if (user != null)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain data quality and integrity by avoiding wrong updates as there might be cases when the value of user may be null due to session timeout or it may be put null intentionally.
It is also a security measure.